# PhpStorm LESS Watcher configuration

Tags: css, less, phpstorm

I am using PhpStorm 8 to work on some LESS files.

`variables.less` gets imported from `styles.less`.

When I save `variables.less` only a `variables.css` is being made.
How do I configure the watcher to transpile only `styles.less > styles.css` and automatically upload `styles.css`?

Here's my current config: [Current watcher config http://www.bilder-upload.eu/upload/e60eb3-1432718715.jpg](http://www.bilder-upload.eu/upload/e60eb3-1432718715.jpg)

Comment: **1)** Enable `Track only root files` option **2)** https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Deployments+in+PhpStorm -- have a look for automatic deployment (although I'm not sure if it will work reliably) in conjunction with File Watcher (sometimes it fails)

Comment: 1) Doesn't work. It's still only variables.less beeing transpiled.

Comment: 2) I tried of course but that doesn't work neither.
3) Pls have a look at your misspelled corrections. (phpsorm)

Comment: 1) Works just fine -- never had an issue with it. Suggestion -- delete file watcher and create new one from scratch. http://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5sxO.png 2) Possibly (Quite likely) your `Output paths to refresh` is not pointing to a correct file (IDE does not re-read whole project looking for changes -- only files pointed here) 3) Thanks, fixed

Comment: Works like a charm now! Thanks. Put down your answer as a question and I'll mark as solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You need to enable `Track only root files` option so that only main file will be compiled.

   If it does not work -- delete your existing watcher and create new one from scratch. Here is mine (as an example -- works fine for me).

   [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5sxO.png]
2. For automatic upload (deployment) -- have a look at the official manual: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Deployments+in+PhpStorm

   If configured correctly but it still does not work -- it's possible (quite likely) that your `Output paths to refresh` is not pointing to a correct file (after File Watcher execution IDE does not re-read whole project looking for changes -- only files pointed here).