# How do I create a file watcher to generate a stylesheet in its own folder from a group of less files?

Tags: phpstorm

How do I create a less file watcher to update `css/style.css` each time `less/style.less` is updated?

Assume that `style.less` imports other less files, like `base.less`.

Specifically, what would I need to enter in the 'New Watcher' dialog box to create this?

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: I recommend you using grunt or gulp for this kind of tasks, they work as a charm.

Comment: Example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30481839/783119

Comment: Thanks @LazyOne that gets me closer. On changing any of my less files, css/style.css now gets created, but it is empty?! Running `lessc less/style.less css/style.css` from the folder that contains the `less/` and `css/` folders works perfectly?

Comment: Screenshots please of what you have there (your current watcher settings) -- maybe you have missed something or did it wrong. **P.S.** You may also set "Show Console" to "always" to see the exact command used.

Comment: Screenshot added.

Comment: Here's the command it is executing: `/usr/local/bin/lessc --no-color style.less ../css/style.css`

Comment: You have specified input and output files ... therefore you have to untick `Create output file from stdout` option

Comment: Working now - thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

1. `Track only root files` must be enabled -- this will prevent from compiling included/partial files separately -- main file will be compiled instead (which automatically includes all used partial files).

   This way you can modify `base.less` (partial file used by main `style.less`) and file watcher will still be triggered for main `style.less` file.
2. "Arguments" filed should include both source (.less) and target (.css) files, something like this: `--no-color $FileName$ ../css/FileNameWithoutExtension$.css`

   This tells to use `$FileName$` as source file (e.g. `style.less`) and put it into `../css/FileNameWithoutExtension$.css` (e.g. `../css/style.css`) -- all paths are relevant to current file (based on "Working directory" field actually, which is by default set to the same folder as the source file)
3. "Output paths to refresh" -- can be empty but better specify the path to generated file there as well (e.g. `../css/FileNameWithoutExtension$.css`) -- this will tell IDE what file gets modified (so it will re-read it) as a result of this File Watcher execution.
4. Since now we have specified input and output files as arguments ... you now have to disable `Create output file from stdout` option .. otherwise IDE will overwrite created file with stdout output (which may result in empty file).

Final File Watcher (here it is done for Windows OS)

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5sxO.png]